# Pulling specific variable from URL with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I get the access_token variable in my URL using javascript .match()?

```
http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=pYBACn8NQeCAVWgiaFG4ZD&expires_in=0
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: you must get it with javascript.match() or your open to other Suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm definitely open to suggestions. The .match() was just a suggestions

Comment: i am working on it :-) you need all this part am i right? pYBACn8NQeCAVWgiaFG4ZD&expires_in=0 or without the =0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same as Parth's solution, but without split and a tiny bit more strict:

```
var url = 'http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=pYBACn8NQeCAVWgiaFG4ZD&expires_in=0';
var token = url.match(/(?:#|#.+&)access_token=([^&]+)/)[1];
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly does this fragment of the expression suggest "(?:#|#.+&)"

Comment: @Karl this is a non-capturing group and means either '#' or '#something&'. I included it to match either '#access_token=' or "#a=b&c=d&access_token=", but not '&other_access_token='

Comment: That's clever. Thanks for explaining it to me. I don't want to just blindly use snippets without fully understanding them beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = 'http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=pYBACn8NQeCAVWgiaFG4ZD&expires_in=0';
var token = url.split("#")[1].match(/access_token=([^&]+)/)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as Eugene's but does not throw exception should the match fail

```
var url = 'http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=pYBACn8NQeCAVWgiaFG4ZD&expires_in=0';
var token = (url.match(/(?:#|#.+&)access_token=([^&]+)/) || ['', null])[1];
```

Returns null if the token is not present in the URL